# Find and loop through rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops

In my spreadsheet, in the first column one row contains a "!".
I need to:

1. find the cell which contains !
2. loop through that row
3. if the cell in the row starts with the letter G, clear the contents.

```
sub looprow()

Cells.Find(what:="!").Activate

for i = 1 to ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Column
If left(Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0,i)).Value, 1) = 'G' Then 
       Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0,i)).ClearContents
       Next
end sub
```

Clearly this doesn't work but as I'm new to vba not sure how to fix this, how do I loop through the row??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub LoopRow()

    Cells.Find(what:="!").Activate

    For Each r In Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlToRight))
        If Left(r.Value, 1) = "G" Then
           r.ClearContents
        End If
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is so helpful thank you very much, I was just not sure how to loop through the cells. very clear!